# Moving Rectangle Up the Screen

Tags: java, android

I have a rectangle I want to move up the screen at a constant rate and am confused as to why my code isn't working. Below is the code:

```
package com.ashmore.MyGame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;

import com.ashmore.framework.Game;
import com.ashmore.framework.Graphics;
import com.ashmore.framework.Image;
import com.ashmore.framework.Screen;
import com.ashmore.framework.Input.TouchEvent;

public class GameScreen extends Screen {
enum GameState {
Ready, Running, Paused
}

GameState state = GameState.Ready;

boolean BarisMoving = false;

private ArrayList<Rect> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rect>();

int bar_x = 32;
int bar_y = 653;
int bar_width = 183;
int bar_height = 648;

Rect bar;
Paint paint;

public GameScreen(Game game) {
super(game);

// Initialize game objects here

bar = new Rect();
bar.set(bar_x, bar_y, bar_width, bar_height);

// Defining a paint object
paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(30);
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

}

private void updateRunning(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, float deltaTime) {

// 1. All touch input is handled here:
int len = touchEvents.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);

BarisMoving = true;

if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

if (ScalesScreen.scaleType.equals("C")) {
rectangles.add(new Rect(56, 400, 80, 435));
//rectangles.get(0);
break;  
}
if (BarisMoving) {

 bar_y = bar_y -= 10;


 }
 for (Rect rect : rectangles) {
if(bar.intersect(rect)) {

checkButtons();

 }

 }

 }

}

private void checkButtons() {
  Log.d("GameScreen","Note and Bar Intersected");
}

@Override
public void paint(float deltaTime) {
Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

Paint paint = new Paint();
Paint paint2 = new Paint();

paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint2.setColor(Color.RED);

for (Rect rect : rectangles) {
g.drawRect(rect, paint);
}

g.drawRect(bar, paint2);

}

private boolean inBounds(TouchEvent event, int x, int y, int width,
        int height) {
    if (event.x > x && event.x < x + width - 1 && event.y > y
            && event.y < y + height - 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

I am probably missing something really basic. However, I can't seem to find the issue. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "isn't working" is a bit vague.  You'll get faster answers if you tell us what's happening.

Comment: I am trying to move the rectangle of the bar up the screen but it isn't moving up with this code

Comment: It's not related to your problem, but shouldn't "bar_y = bar_y -= 10;" just be "bar_y -= 10;"  ?

Comment: How frequently is updateRunning() called?  Is it possible that bar_y is reducing to negative (off-screen) values faster than you can see anything happening?  Or, alternatively, that it isn't called at all?

Comment: It appears to only run when I tap the screen. I changed my code to this:

`if (BarisMoving) {

  bar_y -= 10;
  bar.set(bar_x, bar_y, bar_width, bar_height);

 }`
to see if it would change anything and it makes the rectangle larger in the y direction every time I press the screen until it reaches the other rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem. The problem was where my code was placed in the updateRunning() method. In my question, the setting of the boolean `BarisMoving` was set equal to "true" when there was a touch event:

```
int len = touchEvents.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);

BarisMoving = true;
```

The boolean had to be moved outside of this (above int len = touchEvents.size();) and outside of the whole touch event area to work the way I wanted (outside of the for () { and the ending bracket }).